# Displaying multiple records into single record #excel #vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to display multiple records in excel into single record.

Input data:

| EID | State | Wage | Tax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | CA | 1900 | 10 |
| 123 | AZ | 2345 | 20 |
| 434 | AK | 1800 | 15 |
| 434 | TX | 2500 | 25 |

Expected output:

| EID | State 1 | State 1-Wage | State 1-Tax | State 2 | State 2-Wage | State 2-Tax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | CA | 1900 | 10 | AZ | 2345 | 20 |
| 434 | AK | 1800 | 15 | TX | 2500 | 25 |

both are two different tabs in excel. Vlookup is not working. Not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Why `State 2` is not included in the output? Asking both are different states isn't it?

Comment: Hi! it was a typo, edited the post.

Comment: Also may I know what is your Excel Version, usually we assume members are using `MS365` if you confirm, it will be helpful to post answer accordingly to the version as well

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming there is no `Excel Constraints` as per the tags posted then one could use the following formula which uses a `LAMBDA()` helper function called `MAKEARRAY()`*

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _data, A3:D6,
     _eid, TAKE(_data,,1),
     _ueid, UNIQUE(_eid),
     _databody, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_ueid),COLUMNS(G2:L2),LAMBDA(r,c, INDEX(TOROW(FILTER(DROP(_data,,1),_eid=INDEX(_ueid,r))),c))),
     HSTACK(_ueid, _databody))
```

---

Or, if Unique `EID` is listed in other sheets then fill down method instead of dynamic spill array formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G3</kbd>

```
=TOROW(FILTER($B$3:$D$6,F3=$A$3:$A$6))
```

---

For Older versions:

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$D$6,
  AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$3:$D$6)-ROW($B$3)+1)/
  ($F3=$A$3:$A$6),INT((COLUMN(A1)-1)/3)+1),
  MOD(COLUMNS($ZZ$1:ZZ1)-1,3)+1),"")
```

---

This can also be accomplished using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    GroupByEID = Table.Group(Source, {"EID"}, {{"Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),type table}}),
    ExpandCols = Table.ExpandTableColumn(GroupByEID, "Custom", {"State", "Wage", "Tax", "Index"}, {"State", "Wage", "Tax", "Index"}),
    UnpivotOtherCols = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(ExpandCols, {"EID", "Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    MergeCols = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(UnpivotOtherCols, {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Attribute", "Index"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    PivotCols = Table.Pivot(MergeCols, List.Distinct(MergeCols[Merged]), "Merged", "Value")
in
    PivotCols
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to share the excel? I tried to use the same formula it says too many arguments.

Comment: @Ssmith please download from **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cklfb7k2YAiPOfSa5?e=YXaehm)**

Answer (score 0):

### Transform Data: 'HStack Pivot'

[image: screenshot].

```
=LET(data,A1:D11,
    d,DROP(IF(data="","",data),1),
    ud,TAKE(d,,1),
    dd,DROP(d,,1),
    u,UNIQUE(ud),
    rd,HSTACK(u,IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",u,LAMBDA(rr,r,
        VSTACK(rr,TOROW(FILTER(dd,ud=r))))),1),"")),
    rh,HSTACK(TAKE(data,1,1),TOROW(IF(SEQUENCE((COLUMNS(rd)-1)/COLUMNS(dd)),
        DROP(TAKE(data,1),,1)))),
    VSTACK(rh,rd))
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is here

```
=LET(
uq,UNIQUE(B3:B8),
cn,COUNTA(uq),
st,WRAPCOLS(C3:C8,cn),
wa,WRAPCOLS(D3:D8,cn),
tx,WRAPCOLS(E3:E8,cn),
CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(uq,st,wa,tx),1,2,4,6,3,5,7))
```

[image: Result]